# How to filter timestamp of a Dataframe in pandas when there are duplicate timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this, where each line is an observation in 10-second intervals.

```
timestamp, record, precip
5/14/2020 12:01,1,0.002
5/14/2020 12:01,2,0.002
5/14/2020 12:01,3,0.002
5/14/2020 12:01,4,0.002
5/14/2020 12:01,5,0.002
5/14/2020 12:01,6,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,7,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,8,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,9,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,10,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,11,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,12,0.002
```

I was expecting the file to have the seconds stamped as well but it seems that's an issue I'll have to fix next time I'm on-site. So in the meantime, what would be the best way to filter out the observations at the quarter-hour marks (12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45)? My first thought is maybe to use the 'record' column and use the lowest record value for each quarter-hour mark?

To use the df above as an example, if I wanted to filter out 12:02, I would use the line

```
5/14/2020 12:02,7,0.002
```

since '7' is the lowest record value for all lines stamped 12:02.

the desired df would look something like this but 15 min intervals rather than one-minute intervals.

```
5/14/2020 12:01,1,0.002
5/14/2020 12:02,7,0.002
5/14/2020 12:03,13,0.002
5/14/2020 12:04,19,0.002
5/14/2020 12:05,25,0.002
5/14/2020 12:06,31,0.002
5/14/2020 12:07,37,0.002
```

EDIT: Turns out the way I was reading in the file was my issue. I didn't realize I could read in .dat files the same exact way as .csv files. If I read the files in as a .dat file, it preserved the HH:MM:SS format for the time stamps. Since this is the case, I used

```
df.resample('900s', on 'Date Time').first()
```

and it worked perfectly giving me the df

```
2020-05-14 11:15:00 2020-05-14 11:20:10       1             0.002
2020-05-14 11:30:00 2020-05-14 11:30:00      60             0.002
2020-05-14 11:45:00 2020-05-14 11:45:00     150             0.002
2020-05-14 12:00:00 2020-05-14 12:00:00     240             0.002
2020-05-14 12:15:00 2020-05-14 12:15:00     330             0.002
```

Comment: @jre5212 show expected `df`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I think NYC Coder got what I was thinking of. aparently idk how to format code in a comment so I'll edit the post to include it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the lowest record:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.groupby(by=['timestamp']).first()
print(df)

                      record   precip
timestamp
2020-05-14 12:01:00        1    0.002
2020-05-14 12:02:00        7    0.002
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values('record').drop_duplicates(subset='timestamp')
```

Output:

```
         timestamp  record  precip
0  5/14/2020 12:01       1   0.002
6  5/14/2020 12:02       7   0.002
```